# How to find the time differences of two most recent time sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I have a table that contains these columnss: customer_id, time, tickets.
How can I query the time differences between two most recent time for each customer_id?

I am trying to use row_number() and self join. would like to know if the following would work:

```
Select  customer_id, table.time - tb2.time as time_difference,
(Row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by time DESC) as rank
From  table 
Where rank <=2 
Inner join table t2 on table.customer_id  = t2. Customer_id and table.rank> tb2.rank
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` cancels each other. If you want to get those 2 values, use `OR` or `IN` statement: `rank = 1 OR rank = 2` or `rank IN (1,2)`

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: BTW, tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: @jarlh microsoft sql server

Comment: Syntax error. Should be FROM ... JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ...